Leveraging Extra Data to Enhance Text Clustering
I want to cluster thousands of text data (called corpus A) and find a label for each cluster. Accuary of clustering is significantly important, because I want to use the texts and their labels for training a generative model.
I am using silhouette score for measuring the clustering performance but it does not look good. It is under 0.1 which does not look promising. On the other hand, I have some abstract description (called corpus B) about each text. However, they can not be used as a label. Because two similar text, can have different description with the same meaning. For exmaple, two description about are
Focuses on algorithms used in machine learning
Explores techniques for natural language processing
These description are related to two different text which talking about AI. Notice that it is not possible to check the clustering results by human, because of the huge amount of text data.
Now, my question is can I use these description (B) to improve the clustering?
Also, do you think it is a good idea to use corpus B for evaluating the ML (clustering or any other algorithm) model? for example, in the hyperparameter tuning, calculate the intra and inter cosine similarity on corpus B?
